# How to create a filter to prevent action method from finding null objects

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have created the filter below to restrict access to sections of my application to only users that are logged in. However, my app still complains that the user objects have not been instantiated before the filter fires the redirect. How can I make the redirect kick the user out before the action method has a chance to notice the objects are null?

**Context**

For completeness, it is worth mentioning:

```
UserSession.CurrentOrDefault();
```

Returns an object if it finds values stored in the current session, or null if the session doesn't exist.

**The filter**

```
public class RestrictAccess : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public UserRole RequiredRole { get; set; }

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        var userSession = UserSession.CurrentOrDefault();
        if(userSession != null)
        {
            int userRole = Convert.ToInt32(userSession.User.Role);
            int requiredRole = Convert.ToInt32(this.RequiredRole);
            if(userRole >= requiredRole)
            {
                base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("/");
                return;
            }
        }

        HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("/Session/Create");
    }
}
```

**An example action method that complains:**

```
[RestrictAccess]
public ActionResult Index()
{

    var userSession = UserSession.CurrentOrDefault();

    // This is the part that throws the exception. userSession.User is null here.
    // My expectation was for this to be unreachable if user is null because of the filter.
    var model = new IndexViewModel { User = userSession.User };

    return View(model);
}
```

Comment: You should override AuthorizationAttribute for that

Comment: @VsevolodGoloviznin can you give an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should implement your own `AuthorizeAttribute` for that

```
public class Authorization : AuthorizeAttribute
    {    
        public UserRole RequiredRole { get; set; }
        protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
        {
            var userSession = UserSession.CurrentOrDefault();
            if(userSession != null)
            {
               int userRole = Convert.ToInt32(userSession.User.Role);
               int requiredRole = Convert.ToInt32(this.RequiredRole);
               if(userRole >= requiredRole)
               {

                  return true;
               }
               else
               {
                   return false;
               }
            }
            return false;
        }

        public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
        {
            try
            {
                if (AuthorizeCore(filterContext.HttpContext))
                {
                    // ** IMPORTANT **
                    // Since we're performing authorization at the action level, the authorization code runs
                    // after the output caching module. In the worst case this could allow an authorized user
                    // to cause the page to be cached, then an unauthorized user would later be served the
                    // cached page. We work around this by telling proxies not to cache the sensitive page,
                    // then we hook our custom authorization code into the caching mechanism so that we have
                    // the final say on whether a page should be served from the cache.

                    HttpCachePolicyBase cachePolicy = filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Cache;
                    cachePolicy.SetProxyMaxAge(new TimeSpan(0));
                    cachePolicy.AddValidationCallback(CacheValidateHandler, null /* data */);

                }
                else 
                { 
                   filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult("/Session/Create");

                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult("/Session/Create");
            }
        }

        private void CacheValidateHandler(HttpContext context, object data, ref HttpValidationStatus validationStatus)
        {
            validationStatus = OnCacheAuthorization(new HttpContextWrapper(context));
        }
}
```

Comment: Works like a champ. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

When you call `HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect`, you are going outside of the MVC architecture, so it does not know not to run the action method and so continues and errors.

Instead you should set the [`Result`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.actionexecutingcontext.result(v=vs.118).aspx) of your `ActionExecutingContext filterContext` to a [`RedirectResult`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.redirectresult(v=vs.118).aspx) like so:

```
public class RestrictAccess : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public UserRole RequiredRole { get; set; }

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        var userSession = UserSession.CurrentOrDefault();
        if(userSession != null)
        {
            int userRole = Convert.ToInt32(userSession.User.Role);
            int requiredRole = Convert.ToInt32(this.RequiredRole);
            if(userRole >= requiredRole)
            {
                base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult("/");
                return;
            }
        }

        filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult("/Session/Create");
    }
}
```